# How can I find last index in array with method findIndex() in proper interval? JS

Tags: javascript, arrays

The function using FindIndex should find the latest index of an array of A6, the value of which lies from A6_FROM to A6_TO (more A6_FROM but less A6_TO). Display the found index in OUT-6. If the value is not found, to output FALSE.

```
let a6 = [13, 15, 22, 23, 26, 35, 72];
let a6_from = 23;
let a6_to = 67;
const f6 = () => {
  let res = a6.findIndex((item) => {
    return item > a6_from && item < a6_to;
  });
  document.querySelector('.out-6').innerHTML = `${res}`;
}
```

Comment: And the question and/or problem is...?

Comment: `= res` does the same (implicitly) as `= \`${res}\`;`

Comment: Why `.indexOf()`? Why not `.filter()`? Is this homework?

Comment: Question is: The function using FindIndex should find the latest index of an array of A6, the value of which lies from A6_FROM to A6_TO (more A6_FROM but less A6_TO). Display the found index in OUT-6. If the value is not found, to output FALSE.
I need find last index in the array in the interval wit FIndIndex() plus I can use some another methods but FindIndex() should be the main

Comment: What should the answer be?  5?

Comment: Yes! That's right! It should be not first element but it should be the last/ in our case it should be Index - '5'!

Answer (score 0):

If you find the latest index of array you can use

```
const x = a6[a6.length-1]
```

x will be a6's last item.

```
const f6 = () => {
    a6.findIndex(item => {
       return item === x
    })
}
```

and if you wanna find index with x you can use this way.

Answer (score 0):

This does not use findIndex at all.

It creates an array of objects to store the value and index of the a6 array.  It filters that array so each value is between a6_from and a6_to.  Then it takes the index property of the final element.

```js
let a6 = [13, 15, 22, 23, 26, 35, 72];
let a6_from = 23;
let a6_to = 67;

const meetsCondition = a6.map((value, index) => ({value, index})).filter(e => e.value > a6_from && e.value < a6_to);
const res = meetsCondition[meetsCondition.length - 1].index;

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map()` to produce `[index, element]` pairs, then use `filter()` to obtain only those pairs where the element satisfies the condition.

Prepend the resulting array with `[-1,0]` or some other way to indicate that no element was found. Then use `.pop()[0]` to get the desired index. `-1` would indicate no such element was found.

```js
const a6 = [13, 15, 22, 23, 26, 35, 72];
const a6_from = 23;
const a6_to = 67;

const a6_out = [[-1,0]].concat(
    a6.map((e,i) => [i, e]).filter(([i,e]) => e > a6_from && e < a6_to)
).pop()[0];
//returns -1 if not found
console.log( a6_out );
```